# Split Credit Card Payments for Single Order

Tags: checkout, extensions, payment-methods, ee-1.14.1, partial-payments

Does anyone know of a pre-made module that can take the total cost of an order and split it in the checkout process between multiple credit cards being processed by the same payment method?

If not any ideas of how to split the payment with a custom module without splitting up products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting payment across multiple credit cards like this is referred to as 'partial authorization'. (Note: This is a very different thing from 'partial invoicing' or 'partial capturing', terms you'll also see thrown around.)

Magento's default Authorize.Net gateway includes partial authorization functionality, you just have to enable it in the gateway settings. This works with both Community and Enterprise Edition. See official documentation on the setup and workflow here: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/payment/authorize-net-partial-authorization.html

To my knowledge, this is the only payment method that supports it.

Note that the customer does not get to choose how much to charge to each card. Rather, if the card they enter does not have sufficient funds, they will be prompted to enter another one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw this and unfortunately we do not use authorize.net so this method wouldn't work. I also see that it only works by prompting for an additional payment if the first one doesn't have sufficient funds. Do you know if it's possible to split payments between a single invoice? What I'm seeing is that to split payments magento has to create multiple invoices.

Comment: Again, different things going on. Partial authorization would mean multiple cards being charged in one or more invoices--it charges up to balance of the first card, then the second card, etc, as far as it needs to go for a given invoice. Partial invoicing/capturing means creating an invoice for part of an order's items. That cannot be for an amount independent of the order items.